# ASP.NET WebForms Textbox removes HTML5 pattern attribute

Tags: asp.net, html

Let's say that I have a textbox in a webforms project that looks like this:

```
<asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\s]{4,}"/>
```

Upon rendering, the pattern attribute is removed.  If I add the attribute in the code-behind the attribute is also removed:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("pattern", "[A-Za-z0-9\\s]{4,}");
```

It doesn't matter what the pattern actually is.  It's the attribute named "pattern" that is scrubbed-out upon rendering.  Name the attribute something else and it will be rendered.

I can find no documentation about this and nobody with the same problem.  Has anybody got a work-around, short of writing a custom server control that extends TextBox?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, maybe try updating the HTML Validation in your options? Goto Tools->Text Editor->HTML (Web Forms)->Validation then select HTML5 in the 'Target when no doctype found'. Otherwise, double check that the browser you're using is compatible with HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tracked it down to the use of the Web Experience Toolkit.  Specifically, the part that reads, "Remove the pattern attribute until it is safe to use with jQuery Validation".  Will file an issue with them.

https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew/blob/0f614e0efd50df7970a6fc6bb72104e43b48e8f5/src/plugins/formvalid/formvalid.js#L105

Answer (score 1):

Your patter attribute is not being removed. If you define your pattern as the pattern attribute of the textbox:

```
   <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\s]{4,}"/>
```

Then in your code behind you can check the value:

```
     var r = TextBox1.Attributes["pattern"];
```

Comment: No, it's scrubbed out.  View source and it isn't there to be seen.

Comment: I can see it in View Source: <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\s]{4,}" />

Comment: Yes... I'm looking into it further and it seems to be something related to the local project.  I'm trying to track it down.